# It return 404 on every request after static files settings in appengine-web.xml configured

Tags: java, google-app-engine, static-files

First of all, Thanks in advance to read this.

```
<application>${APPLICATION}</application>
<version>${VERSION}</version>

<system-properties>
    <property
        name="java.util.logging.config.file"
        value="WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties"
    />
    <property name="appengine.datastore.disableChunkSizeWarning" value="false"></property>
</system-properties>

<static-files>
    <include path="/images/**" expiration="40d 0h 0m 0s" />
</static-files>

<precompilation-enabled>true</precompilation-enabled>

<warmup-requests-enabled>true</warmup-requests-enabled>

<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

<inbound-services>
    <service>channel_presence</service>
</inbound-services>
```

above is my appengine-web.xml, after I configured static files setting, every page request returned "error 404"

http://dev.magic-note.appspot.com/

this is the link of the site..

anyone have any suggestions?? anything?? would really appreciated.. thanks guys..

Answer (score 0):

try by extension:

For example:

```
 <static-files>
        <include path="/**.gif" expiration="1d" />
        <include path="/**.png" expiration="1d" />
        <include path="/**.jpg" expiration="1d"  />
        <include path="/**.ico" expiration="1d"  /> 
 </static-files>
```

Answer (score 0):

copy all static files into src\main\webapp folder and include the static file pattern in appengine-web.xml as shown below.

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>YOUR-PROJECT-ID</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <static-files>
    <include path="/**.html" />
    <include path="/**.js" />
    <include path="/**.css" />
  </static-files>
</appengine-web-app>
```